# What are the rules around use of poison in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, poison, dnd-adventurers-league

What, if any, is the official, written, Adventurers League guidance on the harvesting, purchase and/or use of poisons? As a budding assassin, it would help me a lot to understand what is permitted in AL.

Comment: to be clear, you're looking for mentions of harvesting/purchase/use *only in* the four hardcovers, all 41 released (as of this writing) Expeditions modules, and any Epics materials?

Comment: Do you mean basic poison from the PHB, or the poisons from the DMG?

Comment: @nitsua60: your question implies that the four hardcovers, and their contents, are all AL-compliant, which they aren't. I'm looking for AL-sanctioned guidance only. This type of information is typically found in official league material such as the "D&D Adventurers League Player's Guide Version 3.0", as well as ongoing rulings delivered by AL officials via the AL Wiki, and via other channels.

Comment: @Miniman: I am aware of what is written in both the PHB and the DMG, however I have been told in an AL game that this is not necessarily AL compliant and I'd like to be able to confirm if anyone is aware of AL-approved guidance on the subject.

Comment: @Maadiah I know the guidance for both basic poison and DMG poison, I'm asking which you're asking about.

Comment: Ah, then we're apparently out of my depth. If the hardcovers aren't compliant, are the DDEN .pdfs?

Comment: @Miniman: by way of example, I was told today during an offical AL Expedition, by a veteran AL DM, that while I could harvest the venom from a Purple Worm, that I would only be able to use it during the current module and not be able to bring it to a future module. He mentioned that the AL was quite weak on stipulating what was and wasn't permitted with regards to poisons, so I thought I would try and reach out to a wider group to see if anyone had seen anything official.

Comment: @Maadiah Ok, so you mean DMG poison. Cool.

Comment: @ nitsua60: yes, the DDEX pdfs can be considered a legitimate source for rulings.

Comment: @Miniman: actually, both the DMG and PHB have relevant info which I am looking for AL validation of. Another example: p 155 of the PHB states the Poisoner's Kit enables you to craft poisons, however, that doesn't mean the act is AL-compliant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic poison found in the PHB can be bought, created, and used like any other mundane item. The [Adventurer's League Player's Guide](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/ALPGv3.pdf) allows you to use almost all PHB rules.

> D&D Player’s Handbook™ (all rules except rolling ability scores and hit points, some alignment restrictions)

The [Adventurer's League FAQ](http://dndadventurersleague.org/sage/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions_%28FAQ%29#Can_characters_craft_potions_of_healing.3F_Can_they_use_any_material_from_the_Dungeon_Master.27s_Guide.2C_such_as_poisons.2C_or_from_the_Monster_Manual.2C_such_as_stat_blocks_for_familiars_and_wildshaping.3F) specifies that you can only use DMG material (including poisons) if it is explicitly obtainable in a campaign. The full entry contains several irrelevant points, so I've excerpted the bit you care about.

> ## Can characters use any material from the Dungeon Master's Guide, such as poisons?
>
> As a rule, the Dungeon Master's Guide is not a valid character resource for the Elemental Evil storyline season. Since the Dungeon Master's Guide is not a generally valid character resource, characters cannot use any material from it other than magic item descriptions without campaign documentation giving them access.

Comment: @ Miniman: Thanks for posting this, but where does that leave us in terms of PHB compliance with AL? The Crafting section of the PHB on P187 says "You can craft nonmagical objects etc" and P154 says "A poisoner's kit includes the vials, chemicals, and other equipment necessary for the creation of poisons". So I guess my question becomes: is the PHB AL-compliant with regards to poisons, and, if yes, which poisons can I create or use?

Comment: @Maadiah Just as it says, **all** PHB rules are allowed except the exceptions. Poison isn't one of the exceptions, so it's allowed. As for which poisons are allowed, PHB material is allowed, and DMG material is not. You can use any poison from the PHB. The only poison in the PHB is basic poison.