# Extracted poison off an enemy creature. How does one use it?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, poison

In an Adventurer's League session, a couple of weeks ago, one of our battles was against a poisonous creature.

My nature score is pretty decent, and my roll was good, so I managed to extract and save some of the poison from the creature.

My question: How does one use such poisons? Is it even possible to use them, or did I just extract the poison to carry it around?

Comment: related, curious if you think it's a duplicate: [how does crafting poisons work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67951/23970)

Comment: @nitsua60 Ref: duplicate - I'm not actually developing the poison, nor do I have a poisoners kit. This was just an extraction of an existing poison.

Comment: somewhat related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72617/what-are-the-rules-around-use-of-poison-in-adventurers-league

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ask your DM about the Poison Type

To give him guidance, the DMG covers poison types on pages 257-258. With that information, you'll have the knowledge about usage.

Comment: what's your take on this AL player having gained valuable goods (the poisons or poison ingredients) that are not under a "Treasure" subheading? (Cf. ALDMG p.4)

Comment: I made an assumption that AL rules allowed this and would still be up to DM. If wrong, I can delete.

Comment: It's a grey area in AL. All treasure, by AL rule, is converted to GP-equivalent and split equally. But this wasn't in a treasure heading, so maybe it's not treasure? But it'd be of value.... I was sincerely asking where you thought harvested component/ingredient fell in AL's treatment of treasure bookkeeping.